# I want to have my <p> next to each other

Tags: html

I have a question, I'm working on a site and I want this in my website:

Showing at my page at the moment:

> De diensten die wij verlenen op het gebied van beveiligde opbergsystemen zijn:
>       • Openen
>       • Reparatie
>       • 24 op 24 en 7 op 7!
>       • Service
>       • Transport

I want to have the • and the text next to each other. Now they are below each other

the code :

```
 <p class="second">De diensten die wij verlenen op het gebied van beveiligde
opbergsystemen zijn:</p>
    <p class="second">•</p><p class="first"> Openen</p>
    <br>
    <p class="second">•</p><p  class="first"> Reparatie</p>
    <br>
    <p class="second">•</p><p  class="first"> 24 op 24 en 7 op 7!</p>
    <br>
    <p class="second">•</p><p  class="first"> Service</p>
    <br>
    <p class="second">•</p><p  class="first"> Transport</p>
```

The text is dutch so don't mind that

Comment: Instead of paragraphs, why not use unordered lists? That will add the "disc" to your list automatically, and it will line up properly.

Comment: Use `<ul>` and style if necessary.

Comment: Well, a `<p>` tag represents a paragraph, and paragraphs are usually separated and having space above and below. Why use a paragraph tag if you’re not wanting a paragraph of text?

Comment: Add display inline to your `<p>`

Comment: Please look at David's answer below because it is the proper way to achieve what you need. If this does not work for you then please explain why the `<p>` are necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Use `<ul>` tag

```
<ul>
    <li> Openen</li>
    <li> Reparatie</li>
    <li> 24 op 24 en 7 op 7!</li>
    <li> Service</li>
    <li> Transport</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tryed this?

```
<p class="first"><span class="second">•</span>Openen</p>
<p class="first"><span class="second">•</span>Reparatie</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use "[p]" that creates a new paragraph.
"[br]" makes a new break in the line and moves the next set of text to the next line.

So here

```
<p class="second">•</p><p class="first"> Openen</p>
```

you are creating a new paragraph and then • follow by a new paragraph.

That is why your • 's are above eachother.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<div id="container">
    <p class="second">De diensten die wij verlenen op het gebied van beveiligde
    opbergsystemen zijn:</p> 
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p> Openen</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p> Reparatie</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p> 24 op 24 en 7 op 7!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p> Service</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p> transport</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and your css is:
`#container li
{
float left;
}`

will automatically add your bullet to text.